# java.security.InvalidKeyException

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm having trouble that only happens when I'm going to generate signed apk, but when I'm running directly from my Android Studio, everything works normally.

The error happens here:

val key = keyStore? .getKey (KEY_NAME, null)

cipher? .init (Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key)

```
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private fun generateKey() {
        try {
            keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore")

            keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, "AndroidKeyStore")

            keyStore?.load(null)

            keyGenerator?.init(KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(KEY_NAME,
                    KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                    .setBlocenter code herekModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                    .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                    .setEncryptionPaddings(
                            KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)

                    .build())
            keyGenerator?.generateKey()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {
            throw RuntimeException("Failed to get KeyGenerator instance", e)
        } catch (e: NoSuchProviderException) {
            throw RuntimeException("Failed to get KeyGenerator instance", e)
        } catch (e: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        } catch (e: InvalidAlgorithmParameterException) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        } catch (e: CertificateException) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }

    }



@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private fun cipherInit(): Boolean {
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance(
                    KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES + "/"
                            + KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC + "/"
                            + KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
        } catch (e: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {
            throw RuntimeException("Failed to get Cipher", e)
        } catch (e: NoSuchPaddingException) {
            throw RuntimeException("Failed to get Cipher", e)
        }

        try {
            keyStore?.load(null)
            val key = keyStore?.getKey(KEY_NAME, null)
            cipher?.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key)
            return true
        } catch (e: KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException) {
            return false
        } catch (e: KeyStoreException) {
            throw RuntimeException("Failed to init Cipher", e)
        } catch (e: CertificateException) {
            throw RuntimeException("Failed to init Cipher", e)
        } catch (e: UnrecoverableKeyException) {
            throw RuntimeException("Failed to init Cipher", e)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            throw RuntimeException("Failed to init Cipher", e)
        } catch (e: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {
            throw RuntimeException("Failed to init Cipher", e)
        } catch (e: InvalidKeyException) {
            throw RuntimeException("Failed to init Cipher", e)
        }
    }
```

Erro:

Caused by java.security.InvalidKeyException
Only SecretKey is supported

Comment: It looks like a Keypair (Private key and a public key) was created but the code requires a SecretKey , which is a different type of key.
Can you add the code that creates the key in the KeyStore?

Comment: I added pictures in the question.

Comment: Please delete the pictures and copy and paste the code and the stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

You should test the key generation when it's done like so:

```
val keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES")
keyGen.init(128) 
val secretKey = keyGen.generateKey()
```

Hope this helps